# Unity C# IEnumerator isn't changing Sprite Renderer properties

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm making a project where I need an Object to mimic the properties of a set of other Objects with a certain time in between.

For that I used the following `IEnumerator`:

```
public IEnumerator GoBack(GameObject[] go)
{
    for (int i = go.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (go[i] != null)
        {
            GameObject g = go[i];
            transform.position = g.transform.position;
            sprRenderer.flipX = g.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX;
            sprRenderer.sprite = g.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
                
            Destroy(go[i]);
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(rollBack);
        }
    }

    GetComponent<Animator>().Play("EndTurnBack");
}
```

This basically alters my Object to be equal to the `position`, `sprite` and `flipX` of the object it is mimicking.
The problem is that only the `position` appears to work and I have no clue as to why

I tried printing in the console what was the sprite and `flipX` of my Object for each iteration and it is exactly what I want but the results don't appear on the screen.

Comment: Is it useful to directly change `flipX` and `sprite` (e.g. `sprRenderer.flipX = !sprRenderer.flipX`) for each iteration?

Comment: Do you also animate those properties somewhere? If so you will need to turn of the `Animator` during your loop .. otherwise it will hold a lock on the property and overrule your code changes as the animator is one of the last things to be applied within a frame